# Search Queries for Gerrit

Tags: java, gerrit

I am doing some basic search queries for Gerrit but could not find anything much.

I want a gerrit query which can fetch the list based on multiple authors  or based on created and updated date.

I am doing the following query in java but need a query which can fetch list based on multiple authors

```
gerritApi.changes().query("project:" + "Test-Project"+"+"+"status:merged").get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for all opened changes from AUTHOR-1 or AUTHOR-2 do the following:

```
curl --request GET --user USER https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=\(owner:AUTHOR-1+OR+owner:AUTHOR-2\)+AND+status:open
```

Or in java:

```
gerritApi.changes().query("(owner:AUTHOR-1 OR owner:AUTHOR-2) + AND status:open").get();
```

Comment: You are missing some spaces, and concatenation is not necessary in your Java example (as you are not using any variables there)...

Comment: Your're write... I just removed the unneeded quotes.